# Using JQueryUI Slider to change Layer Display (Leaflet)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery

Can't seem to figure out how to use JQueryUI Slider to change the layer display on my leaflet map.
Scenario is basically, When user slides bar across a dfferent layer shows up on the map (in years)
Below is the slider script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set up an array to hold the years
    var years = [1111, 1112];

    var activeYear = 

    $(".slider")

        // activate the slider with options
        .slider({ 
            max: years.length-1, 
            value: activeYear 
        })       
        // add pips with the labels set to "years"
        .slider("pips", {
            rest: "label",
            labels: years
        })
        // and whenever the slider changes, change map display layer
        .on("slidechange", function(e,ui) {
             **UNSURE OF CODE HERE**
        });
</script>
```

My layers are listed earlier in the map script in a different div, a sample one is

```
var basemaps = {
oneoneoneone: L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'map:1111',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    format: 'image/png'

}),
```

Am i able to relate the oneoneoneone layer to the slider array value 1111 and then when slider is set on that section it will display the layer on the map?

Comment: You would probably be interested in [LeafletSlider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider)

Answer (score 5):

As ghybs suggests in the comment above, you may find the [LeafletSlider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) useful. It has some idiosyncrasies that make it unsuitable for some uses, but if all you need to do is step through consecutive years, it should suit your purposes fine. If you pass it a `L.layerGroup` object with the layers you want to use, it will place a JQueryUI slider control on the map, which you can use to step through your layers. You can also add a `time` property (either as text or as a numeric value in seconds) to each layer, and the plugin will use this to label the slider as it is moved:

```
var oneoneoneone = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
  layers: 'map:1111',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.1.0',
  format: 'image/png',
  time: '1111'
});

var oneoneonetwo = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
  layers: 'map:1112',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.1.0',
  format: 'image/png',
  time: '1112'
});

var years = [oneoneoneone, oneoneonetwo];
layerGroup = L.layerGroup(years);
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
  layer: layerGroup,
  follow: true
});
map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

By default, it shows all layers up to the current slider position, but if you specify `follow: true` in the slider options, it will only show one layer at a time.

Here is an example using LeafletSlider with some radar data from a WMS:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/260hffor/

Comment: thanks man! will help me heaps, will see how i go implementing it and get back to you!

Comment: So tried to get it working, and i think it is close, i even tried all of the same code/data as your jsfiddle, but for some reason the slider wont show up (the mouse even changes from the hand to the pointer when i hover over the top right section where its meant to be.

The only thing i can think of is that i am importing the javascript code wrong? otherwise what else could it be? maybe a setting on my computer?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code. Are there any errors in the debug console?

Comment: No worries, I'll try troubleshoot my code for errors and get back to you 

Comment: Using firebug on firefox my code popped up with this exception

'        TypeError: L.control.sliderControl is not a function
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({       '
Does that mean that my jquery script is not passing into my code correctly?

Comment: Did you include a reference to the [LeafletSlider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) in your code? In the jsfiddle, [the plugin is included](http://rawgit.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/master/dist/leaflet.SliderControl.min.js) in the "External Resources" section, sourced via [rawgit](https://rawgit.com/), but you would probably be using a local copy.

Comment: yeah checked my script imports and seem fine, say my file was on the desktop in a folder called 'slidertest' how would you write the import? would it be like '<script src="Desktop/SliderControl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'

Comment: @cmca It seems that the JQueryUI CSS file needs to be loaded, e.g.: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">